# HTML5 audio doesn' work with Wordpress + Firefox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firefox

I'm working on a custom audio player widget. The code works on a static HTML page in Firefox and Chromium. The code also works within the Wordpress site in Chromium. However, when viewing the Wordpress page in Firefox, the promise gets stuck as `pending` and never resolves.

Here's an abridged version of the script:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  function addAudio(podcast) {
    let container = document.getElementById('audio-container')

    if (container === null) {
      const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
      container = document.createElement('div')  
      container.setAttribute('id', 'audio-container')
      body.insertBefore(container, body.firstChild)
    }

    const audio = document.createElement('audio')
    audio.setAttribute('id', 'audio-media')
    container.appendChild(audio)

    const source = document.createElement('source')
    source.setAttribute('src', podcast.audio)
    audio.appendChild(source)
  }

  document.getElementById('play-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    playAudio()
  }

  function playAudio() {
    const audio = document.getElementById('audio-media')
    let playPromise = audio.play()

    console.log('playPromise', playPromise)

    if (playPromise !== undefined) {
      playPromise.then(() => {
        console.log('success')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("ERROR", err)
      })
    } else {
      console.log('playPromise is undefined')
    }
  }

  addAudio(currentTrack)

})
```

When I run this on a static page in Chromium or Firefox, or when I run this as a Wordpress widget I get the following output:

```
playPromise Promise {<pending>}
success
```

and the track starts to play. However, when I run this as a Wordpress widget in Firefox, I only get `playPromise Promise {<pending>}`. Sometimes I eventually get this too:

```
Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the “this” object is incorrect.
```

Except I don't use `this` anywhere in my code, and I've found things elsewhere implying that warning may be from a bug in Firefox.

Stranger still, if I even try a simple HTML5 audio component in the Wordpress plugin:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../path/to/track.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Firefox will crap out and be stuck in a loading state (the rest of the page loads, but the track never starts). Yet again, as a static page this works fine, and as a Wordpress plugin accessed via Chromium it works fine.

Also, using Wordpress's native player (which uses audio elements under the hood) doesn't work in Firefox:

```
<?php $attr = array(
  'src' => $feedz[0]['audio'], 
  'loop' => '', 
  'autoplay' => '', 
  'preload' => 'none' ); 
echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr ); ?>
```

Extra details:

- Debian 9
- Locally hosted with Apache 2
- Firefox 60.4.0esr
- Chromium Version 71.0.3578.80

What makes a promise get hung up while pending instead of failing?

Is this a bug in Firefox? Wordpress? Am I doing something wrong and getting away with it on one browser and not the other?